# How can we modify "href" using jquery counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a web page containing some links .

```
<div class="accordion-list">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li class="accordion-item">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-link">Heading 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li><a href="xyz.com">Registrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="xyz.com" >Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="xyz.com" >Mortgages</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

       <li class="accordion-item">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-link">Heading 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li><a href="abc.com">Registrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="abc.com" >Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="abc.com" >Mortgages</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

desired output

```
   <div class="accordion-list">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li class="accordion-item">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-link">Heading 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li><a href="xyz.com#item1">Registrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="xyz.com#item2" >Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="xyz.com#item3" >Mortgages</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

       <li class="accordion-item">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-link">Heading 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-list">
          <li><a href="abc.com#item1">Registrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="abc.com#item2" >Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="abc.com#item3" >Mortgages</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

i tried

```
$(".sub-list a").each(function() {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + ???);
});
```

Can someone tell me how can we get the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zlkLt/

```
$(".sub-list").each(function() {
   var links = $(this).find('a');
   links.each(function(i) {
     var _href = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr("href", _href + "#item" + (i + 1));
   });
});
```

(You can see the updated href via js console)

Comment: I deliberately left inner **each** for OP, so that he can try finding correct approach. But you ruined it. ;)   +1 anyways.

Comment: This prints out '01', '11', '21'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var num = 0;
$(".sub-list a").each(function() {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + "#item"+ ++num);
    if (num == 3){
        num = 0;
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jt2Z/)

This basically creates a variable outside the `each`, then for every link, it goes up by `1` digit. When it gets to `3`, it resets and goes back to `0`.

[Updated jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jt2Z/1/)

Comment: list count is not known it could be more and different for accordion-item

Comment: we can't check num==3 as its different for all accordian-item

Comment: Look at the newer fiddle. I'm in middle of editing post! @Manoj

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery.each** also passes the index to your callback method.

```
$(".sub-list a").each(function(i) {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + '#item' + (i+1) ); // i starts from 0
});
```

This will update all href with

```
<li><a href="xyz.com#item1">Registrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="xyz.com#item2" >Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="xyz.com#item3" >Mortgages</a></li> 

 <li><a href="abc.com#item4">Registrations</a></li>
          <li><a href="abc.com#item5" >Contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="abc.com#item6" >Mortgages</a></li>
```

But this is not what you expected. You will have to use the selector which will give all href in first   then in second. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(".sub-list").find("a").each(function(){

$(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href")+"item"+($(this).parent().index()+1));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this.

```
$(".sub-list").each(function(index, element){
  $(element).find('li a').each(function(i, element){
    var href_val = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href_val+"#item"+i);
  });
});
```

Comment: $(this).attr('href', href_val+"#item"+(i+1)); its working now thanks